# Extract the date from string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have the creation time in following format:
Mon Mar 25 2013 15:28:21 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
How can I use PHP to extract the date from this string?

Comment: What do you want to do with the date?

Comment: Have you seriously made a basic search before asking ?

Comment: You mean `Mar 25 2013`?

Comment: I want the date in 2013-03-25 15:28:21 format

Answer (score 4):

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s e', 'Mon Mar 25 2013 15:28:21 GMT+0000');
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note this requires at least PHP 5.3.0, for more information see documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Thanks that's fulfils my request completely. THanks

Comment: @barry-staes - If people are still developing for unsupported PHP versions < 5.3.0 then it is really time for them to upgrade now

Comment: No need for `->setTimezone()` since DateTime object is already set to UTC offset.

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

> Example #1 A date_parse() example
>
> ```
> <?php
> print_r(date_parse("2006-12-12 10:00:00.5"));
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [year] => 2006
>     [month] => 12
>     [day] => 12
>     [hour] => 10
>     [minute] => 0
>     [second] => 0
>     [fraction] => 0.5
>     [warning_count] => 0
>     [warnings] => Array()
>     [error_count] => 0
>     [errors] => Array()
>     [is_localtime] => 
> )
> ```

From here on, you should be able to parse `Mon Mar 25 2013 15:28:21 GMT+0000`. Or consider using `explode(' ', $parts)` to split it into a `$parts[2]='25'` array.